# Three JS | Collada loader textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have problem with threeJS **collada loader**.
I receive **dae** model with all **textures** from backend. After, i parse images (textures) and create materials array.

```
let materials = [];
textures.forEach((texture) => {
  let loadedTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(texture.url);
  let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: loadedTexture });
});
```

[image]

Then I load **dae** model and try to append my array with materials:

```
colladaLoader.load(daeModelFile, (collada) => {
  let model = collada.scene;

  dae.traverse( ( child ) => {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
      child.material = materials;
    }
  });

  mainScene.add(model);
});
```

But instead of this:
[image]

I received this one:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading a `dae` file with `THREE.ColladaLoader2`, it is not necessary to manually apply the textures. This is done by the loader. Please check out the source code of this example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

BTW: Don't use `THREE.ColladaLoader` anymore. This is an old implementation that will be replaced with `THREE.ColladaLoader2` in the next release.

`R87`

Comment: I have used typescript, and don't find ColladaLoader2 in ts

Comment: I also load zip archive from backend, then unzip dae file, load him. After unzip texture images and load them by TextureLoader.

Comment: This is not the intended workflow since you don't respect the texture related data in the collada file. As a workaround, try to apply this code when you create your textures for this particular model `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT= THREE.RepeatWrapping`. But still you shouldn't load these textures manually.